# Spring cloud gateway unable to resolve service id from eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

Followed the [spring guides](https://spring.io/guides) to build the eureka server, spring cloud gateway and a sample rest service.

However, the gateway is unable to retrieve the urls using the service name from the eureka server.
The registering of the gateway and service seems to be fine. 
It works fine when the actual endpoint is provided instead of the service id.
I am Unable to understand why the gateway is not resolving the service id from the eureka. Am I missing any configurations ?

Error message:

```
2018-09-05 23:20:17.751  INFO 47037 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client: localhost instantiated a LoadBalancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=localhost,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2018-09-05 23:20:17.756  INFO 47037 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2018-09-05 23:20:17.760  INFO 47037 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client localhost initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=localhost,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@107dc063
2018-09-05 23:20:17.822 ERROR 47037 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8080/rest-service/hello]

org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.NotFoundException: Unable to find instance for localhost
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.LoadBalancerClientFilter.filter(LoadBalancerClientFilter.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$GatewayFilterAdapter.filter(FilteringWebHandler.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter.filter(OrderedGatewayFilter.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.lambda$filter$0(FilteringWebHandler.java:115) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
```

Service Registry: [image]

Attaching the links to the code:

- [Eureka Server](https://github.com/adnanmamajiwala/eureka-server.git)
- [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://github.com/adnanmamajiwala/spring-cloud-gateway.git)
- [Rest service](https://github.com/adnanmamajiwala/rest-service.git)

Comment: have you found a solution? get similar issue

Comment: @roberttrudel the issue was fixed by adding the property `spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id= true` in gateway code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was with the way spring cloud gateway accesses the service names from eureka, it was case sensitive. The fix was to add the following properties in application.yml

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id= true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled= true
```

[I have created a sample project to show all of them working together](https://github.com/adnanmamajiwala/spring-cloud-sample).

Comment: after debugging for like 3 hours, your answer here worked for me, i suspect the eureka names need just to be forced lower case for whatever reason. was a pain to  get this working... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you were using `WebClient` to make API calls to other micro-services from the spring cloud gateway-service, make sure that you annotate `WebClient.Builder` in your configuration class.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
public class ContentConfig {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}
```

And then inside your provider or service class `@AutoWired` the WebClient bean by,

```java
@Autowired
public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;
```

Comment: Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer make sure to add the DiscoveryClient dependency:

> 10.2 DiscoveryClient Route Definition Locator
>
> The Gateway can be configured to create routes based on services registered with a DiscoveryClient compatible service registry.
>
> To enable this, set spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true and make sure a DiscoveryClient implementation is on the classpath and enabled (such as Netflix Eureka, Consul or Zookeeper).

See [10.2 DiscoveryClient Route Definition Locator](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/2.1.x/multi/multi__configuration.html)